# Non-polling implementation of std::when_any()

Tags: c++, concurrency, promise, c++17

The following — I claim — is a implementation of `when_any` from the C++ Concurrency TS, except without all the baggage around `when_any_result`. (This makes `when_any` and `when_all` have exactly the same function signature, which is elegant IMHO.)

My futures are just like `std::future`, except that they support one additional member function:

```
    auto then(F f) -> future<decltype(f(std::move(*this)))>;
```

(My futures also support `next(F)`, `recover(F)`, and `fallback_to(V)` as specified in [N3865 "More improvements to std::future<T>"](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n3865.pdf), and also `bool ready() const`, but those aren't used in this code.)

The Concurrency TS's [`when_any`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/when_any) philosophically-incorrectly returns a ready future when called with zero arguments. My version doesn't treat that case specially, and so the natural behavior falls out: the internal `promise` is destroyed before any 1 of the 0 provided futures has become ready, and so `when_any(/*zero args*/)` returns a ready future whose `get()` will throw `broken_promise`.

I'm a little concerned by the apparently necessary use of lock-free programming. Am I missing an "easier" (higher-level) way to do it?

```
#include "scratch/bits/concurrency/future-and-promise.h"
#include "scratch/bits/smart-ptrs/shared-ptr.h"
#include "scratch/bits/tuple/tuple.h"
#include "scratch/bits/type-traits/decay.h"

#include <atomic>
#include <utility>

namespace scratch::detail {

template<class... Futures>
struct when_any_shared_state {
    promise<tuple<Futures...>> m_promise;
    tuple<Futures...> m_tuple;
    std::atomic<bool> m_done;
    std::atomic<bool> m_count_to_two;

    when_any_shared_state(promise<tuple<Futures...>> p) :
        m_promise(std::move(p)), m_done(false), m_count_to_two(false) {}
};

} // namespace scratch::detail

namespace scratch {

template<class... Futures>
auto when_any(Futures... futures) -> future<tuple<Futures...>>
{
    using shared_state = detail::when_any_shared_state<Futures...>;
    using R = tuple<Futures...>;
    promise<R> p;
    future<R> result = p.get_future();

    auto sptr = make_shared<shared_state>(std::move(p));
    auto satisfy_combined_promise =
        [sptr](auto f) {
            if (sptr->m_done.exchange(true) == false) {
                if (sptr->m_count_to_two.exchange(true)) {
                    sptr->m_promise.set_value(std::move(sptr->m_tuple));
                }
            }
            return f.get();
        };
    sptr->m_tuple = tuple<Futures...>(futures.then(satisfy_combined_promise)...);
    if (sptr->m_count_to_two.exchange(true)) {
        sptr->m_promise.set_value(std::move(sptr->m_tuple));
    }
    return result;
}

} // namespace scratch
```

[(GitHub link)](https://github.com/Quuxplusone/from-scratch/blob/master/include/scratch/bits/concurrency/when-any.h)

---

I've linked this post from [over here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46329595/1424877). I wrote some external documentation there as well: :)

> You attach a continuation to each incoming future (using `then`). This continuation holds a `shared_ptr` to a shared state. The shared state holds a count-to-one (`m_done`) and a count-to-two (`m_count_to_two`). Each continuation that executes will increment the count-to-one; if it's the winner, it will also increment the count-to-two. The main thread will also increment the count-to-two after it finishes setting up all this stuff. As soon as the count-to-two has reached 2 (indicating that the main thread finished setting up *and* at least one continuation has executed), we'll call `set_value` on the promise corresponding to `when_any`'s return future. Ta-da!

---

To explicitly answer Harald's question in the comments

> what is the purpose of the double check using m_done and m_count_to_two, what necessitates that ? Isn't checking on m_done enough?

- We need at least `m_done`, "intuitively".
- But if *all* we had was `m_done`, we wouldn't be able to bump it in the main thread.
- So when the first continuation finished and bumped `m_done`, it would have no way of knowing whether the main thread had finished writing to `sptr->m_tuple`.
- If the continuation tried to move-out-of `sptr->m_tuple` while the main thread was still writing into it, we'd have a race condition.
- So we need *another* counter to indicate that (exactly) one of the continuation threads is ready *and* that the main thread is ready.

...Now it does occur to me that we could use a mutex lock instead, [like this](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/176241/16369), and then we could get rid of the count-to-two *and* make `m_done` non-atomic. But I currently think I prefer the lockfree version as easier to reason about.(!)

Comment: Curious i can't find the reference that documents how the part `tuple<Futures...>(futures.then(satisfy_combined_promise)...)` works, you're creating a tuple with the template types from the function call, but then calling a function on each of the parameters (at least that's my interpretation). I didn't know this works, the parameter pack documentation on cppreference doesn't seem to cover this case. I am assuming the results of the function call get expanded into a comma separated list ?

Comment: @HaraldScheirich: You're correct! (I think.) It's plain vanilla pack-expansion, but with all the parens it may look worse than it is. Basically if `xs` is a pack, then `f(g(xs)...)` expands into `f(g(x1), g(x2), g(x3))`. In this case I've got `f(xs.g(h)...)` expanding into `f(x1.g(h), x2.g(h), x3.g(h))`. Does that help and/or jibe with your existing understanding? :)

Comment: yes that was what I would have expected for that syntax. I'm still trying to figure out the specs on `then` and `when_any`. Looking at your code, if you don't mind what is the purpose of the double check using `m_done` and `m_count_to_two, what necessitates that ? Isn't checking on `m_done`  enough ? btw thanks for posting this, it's giving me a chance to check this part of c++ out a little bit more.

Comment: @HaraldScheirich: Thanks! :) I've just updated this post with an explanation (quoted) of my logic.

Answer (score 1):

After Harald's questions, it occurred to me that I could have done it with a plain old mutex instead of all the lock-free stuff. But if I do it this way, then it starts to look like "blocking". I think it's fine — this use of a mutex isn't any more harmful than the use of a mutex in the innards of `promise`/`future` in the first place — but in a strange way I'm finding it *harder* to reason about this new version than about the version in the question.

```
#include "scratch/bits/concurrency/future-and-promise.h"
#include "scratch/bits/concurrency/lock-guard.h"
#include "scratch/bits/concurrency/mutex.h"
#include "scratch/bits/concurrency/unique-lock.h"
#include "scratch/bits/smart-ptrs/shared-ptr.h"
#include "scratch/bits/tuple/tuple.h"
#include "scratch/bits/type-traits/decay.h"

#include <utility>

namespace scratch::detail {

template<class... Futures>
struct when_any_shared_state {
    promise<tuple<Futures...>> m_promise;
    tuple<Futures...> m_tuple;
    mutex m_mtx;  // protects m_done and m_tuple
    bool m_done;

    when_any_shared_state(promise<tuple<Futures...>> p) :
        m_promise(std::move(p)), m_done(false) {}
};

} // namespace scratch::detail

namespace scratch {

template<class... Futures>
auto when_any(Futures... futures) -> future<tuple<Futures...>>
{
    using shared_state = detail::when_any_shared_state<Futures...>;
    using R = tuple<Futures...>;
    promise<R> p;
    future<R> result = p.get_future();

    auto sptr = make_shared<shared_state>(std::move(p));
    auto satisfy_combined_promise =
        [sptr](auto f) {
            unique_lock lk(sptr->m_mtx);
            if (!sptr->m_done) {
                sptr->m_done = true;
                lk.unlock();
                sptr->m_promise.set_value(std::move(sptr->m_tuple));
            }
            return f.get();
        };
    {
        lock_guard lk(sptr->m_mtx);
        sptr->m_tuple = tuple<Futures...>(futures.then(satisfy_combined_promise)...);
    }
    return result;
}

} // namespace scratch
```

Comment: I have a rather strange question, but are you by some chance Arthur O'Dwyer? I've seen almost all of his talks, and they were awesome!

Comment: @Incomputable: Indeed I am. Thanks for the compliment! :)

Answer (score 1):

It took me a while to figure this one out but thanks again for posting it was a good way to read up on these new concepts. I find the locking version easier to understand, as it expresses the key concept of having to protect the construction of the `m_tuple` much better. That was the part that I was struggling with on the atomic counter version. In that case a continuation function might have triggered while the constructor or the assignment operator are still running in the main thread.

I am torn about your change to the return value type, yes I agree that this makes the signatures the same but it now seems to require an iteration over the returned tuple to find the future that is ready. I can see where the standards committee is coming from.

I wonder if using the unique lock and unlocking early is worth the extra effort that might be in Instatiating a unique lock vs a lock guard.

As both versions seem to work the faster one should probably win ;)